# jQuery: element position/index of the same tagname

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is an example element

```
<div id="random_parent">
  <h1></h1>
  <h2></h2>
  <h2></h2>
  <h1 class="target"></h1>
  <h2></h2>
  <h2 class="target"></h2>
  <h2></h2>
</div>
```

Now I create these two jQuery objects:

```
var j_h1 = $("#random_parent h1.target");
var j_h2 = $("#random_parent h2.target");
```

I need a function, that outputs the position/index of an element inside of a parent class. Example:

```
posElement(j_h1) == 2 // The second child with the tagname h1
posElement(j_h2) == 4 // The fourth child with the tagname h2
```

How do I write such a function? Thank You

Comment: I have written an answer with a code snippet. Run and check if this is what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)  function to get the effective index within array of dom objects of similar type.

Used `.prop("tagName")` to get the tagname of the current element before index search in function.

```js
function posElement(listItem) {
  var tmp = listItem.parent().find(listItem.prop("tagName"));
  return ($(tmp).index(listItem) + 1);
}
var j_h1 = $("#random_parent h1.target");
var j_h2 = $("#random_parent h2.target");
console.log(posElement(j_h1));
console.log(posElement(j_h2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="random_parent">
  <h1></h1>
  <h2></h2>
  <h2></h2>
  <h1 class="target"></h1>
  <h2></h2>
  <h2 class="target"></h2>
  <h2></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: First all all there are multiple elements with the same id (classes should have been used). What happens when you aim at the third element with the id=baz ( this one: <li id="baz">zoo</li> ). Would it output 3? Don't think so

Comment: @user3600124 u probably have'nt reloaded the page, i had edited the answer 7 minutes back

Comment: This one works almost right. The only problem is that elements of other parent elements get selected as well

Comment: @user3600124 made the edit. Search only in immediate parents.

Comment: If you don't want parent only solution is to add a parameter in the function and pass `"h1#random_parent"`.

Comment: @user3600124 pls accept it if it solved the problem.

Comment: Not sure if that is the best solution though. I'll surely accept your answer if no better solutions come up

Answer (score 0):

It's [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function. For your code:

```
$("h1").index(j_h1) + 1; // 2
$("h2").index(j_h2) + 1; // 4
```

Comment: Nice , but it will result as 1 and 3

Comment: You are right, I've made an edit. Sure, it's just an array and it's obviously zero-indexed :) . @Iceman: Yes, it does work: [JSBin example](https://jsbin.com/pudagiwumo/1/edit?html,js,console).

Comment: @ArkadiuszMichowski I was actually referring to the 1 & 3 before your edit. works now. cheers. :D

Answer (score 0):

you can go for a function like this. this takes the element to be searched, type of the element and the context (parent element inside which the children need to be searched.)

```js
function posElement(element, tagname,context) {

  return "This is " + ($(tagname,context).index(element) + 1) +" child with tagname " + tagname
}
   
var parent = $("#random_parent");
var j_h1 = $("#random_parent h1.target");
var j_h2 = $("#random_parent h2.target");
  
  
console.log(posElement(j_h1,"h1",parent)); 
console.log(posElement(j_h2,"h2",parent));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="random_parent">
  <h1></h1>
  <h2></h2>
  <h2></h2>
  <h1 class="target"></h1>
  <h2></h2>
  <h2 class="target"></h2>
  <h2></h2>
</div>

 <div id="random_parent_1">
 <h1></h1>
 <h2></h2>
 </div>
```